# Numpy gradient of big 3D array consumes all memory

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, gradient

I'm using numpy to compute the gradient of a big 3D array with possibly arbitrary dimensions

```
import numpy as np
N = 512
Nz = 512
result = np.zeros((N,N,Nz)).astype(np.float32)
gx, gy, gz = np.gradient(result)
```

The problem is, the PC results unusable for a period of minutes, since ubuntu dedicates most of my 4gb of RAM to this algorithm.

I tried cython but I got the same result. Is anything better to do than this brute-force approach of using the numpy gradient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course there's something better than this brute-force approach.  What are you doing with the gradients?  Do you really need all elements of all the gradients all at the same time?

Comment: I use them to warp a 3D scalar field, basically:

import warp
warp.warp(field, gx,gy,gz, N, Nz,k)
...
# cython
warp(...):
...
        for x from 0<=x<N:    
            for y from 0<=y<N:
                for z from 0<=z<Nz:
                    u = x-k*gx[x,y,z] # f^(-1)
                    v = y-k*gy[x,y,z]
                    w = z-k*gz[x,y,z]
                    try:
                        field2[x,y,z] = resample(field,u,v,w)#field[u,v,w]
                    except: pass